# MongoDB Replication (Two Set) Not Switching to Primary

Tags: mongodb

I have two set server, both setup as replication set.

And I went to test whether the SLA of 12 seconds electing new primary was done. However, even after 30 mins of waiting, the secondary still does not become the Primary Set.

Why does this happen?
[image]

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: The majority of members must be up and reachable. 1 member out of 2 is not the majority!